# select unique entries based on values from another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table in below format contains list of admins with their primary and secondary work locations. From below I only want to select entries based on their primary locations and unfortunately in the table, I do not have a column to clearly differntiate between primary and secondary site.

Relation between sites:

| Primary | Secondary |
| --- | --- |
| Bangalore | Chennai |
| Chennai | Kolkatta |
| Mumbai | Chennai |

Data Table:

| Name | City |
| --- | --- |
| Ashok | Bangalore |
| Ashok | Chennai |
| Prakash | Mumbai |
| Prakash | Chennai |
| Suresh | Kolkata |
| Rajesh | Chennai |
| Rajesh | Kolkata |

Desired result:

| Name | City |
| --- | --- |
| Ashok | Bangalore |
| Suresh | Kolkata |
| Rajesh | Chennai |
| Prakash | Mumbai |

Can this be achieved in select? Any help is really appreciated.

tried distinct on and array_agg and either of them didn't produce close enough results.